# Verificar se contem Dados em tabela SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Como verificar se uma tabela SQLite do Android contem dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há duas maneiras de fazer isso:

Usando um `SELECT COUNT`:

```
// Obtenha a instância de SQLiteDatabase
SQLiteDatabase db = ...;

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABELA", null);

if (cur != null) {
    cur.moveToFirst();
    if (cur.getInt (0) == 0) {
        // Tabela esta vazia, preencha com seus dados iniciais
    } else {
        // Tabela ja contem dados.
    }
}
```

**Uma recomendação para tabelas grandes pode ser a consulta:**

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABELA)
```

Nessa consulta a engine pode parar ao encontrar o primeiro elemento, sendo mais performática.

Ficando:

```
// Obtenha a instância de SQLiteDatabase
SQLiteDatabase db = ...;

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABELA)", null);

if (cur != null) {
    cur.moveToFirst();
    if (cur.getInt (0) == 0) {
        // Tabela esta vazia, preencha com seus dados iniciais
    } else {
        // Tabela ja contem dados.
    }
}
```

Ou usando o [`DatabaseUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html):

```
// Obtenha a instância de SQLiteDatabase
SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
long numOfEntries = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "TABELA");

if(numOfEntries == 0l) {
    // Tabela vazia, preencha com seus dados iniciais
} else {
    // Tabela ja contem dados.
}
```

Olhando o código fonte do [`DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(SQLiteDatabase db, String table)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%2Cjava.lang.String%29). Os dois fazem a mesma coisa.

Fontes:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397757/how-can-i-check-to-see-if-my-sqlite-table-has-data-in-it

Comment: porque numOfEntries == 0l ? Não seria 0?

Comment: O retorno da `queryNumEntries` é do tipo `long`, só usei o `0l` (0 `long`) para evitar um cast implícito. Bobeira mesmo, pode usar o `0` sem problemas.